# How to use downloaded dataset to train Tensorflow image recognition model

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to build an image recognition model with a dataset I downloaded from [this site](https://zenodo.org/records/6907230) but I'm not sure how to load it in as a dataset.

I tried this:

```
dataset_name = 'underwater_dataset'
(train_dataset, test_dataset), dataset_info = tfds.load(name=dataset_name,
                                                       split=['train', 'test'],
                                                       data_dir='C:/Users/tvish/OneDrive/Desktop/Submersible/underwater_dataset',
                                                       shuffle_files=True,
                                                       with_info=True,
                                                       as_supervised=True)

image, label = next(iter(train_dataset.take(1)))
 
plt.imshow(image)
plt.title(label.numpy())
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

but got this error:

```
Did you mean: underwater_dataset -> bee_dataset ?

The builder directory C:\Users\tvish\OneDrive\Desktop\Submersible\underwater_dataset\underwater_dataset doesn't contain any versions.
No builder could be found in the directory: C:/Users/tvish/OneDrive/Desktop/Submersible/underwater_dataset/ for the builder: underwater_dataset.
No registered data_dirs were found in:
        - C:/Users/tvish/OneDrive/Desktop/Submersible/underwater_dataset/
```

Comment: Its seems like TensorFlow Datasets TFDS is having trouble finding the dataset builder for the dataset you are trying to load. Its suggests that TFDS does not find a builder for the dataset “underwater_dataset”. This issue due to a few reasons, such as the dataset not being part of the TFDS catalog, incorrect naming or missing files. Since you have your dataset stored locally, you can use TensorFlow’s ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory to load the dataset.